# grep "*.JPG" not returning entries ending in .JPG

Tags: linux, grep

When I run this command `ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids`, I get 100s of entries in the following format. Notice the endings of the images are either PNG or JPG

```
-rw-r--r--  1 moi  staff      189280 Oct 29  2011 IMG_0041.PNG
-rw-r--r--  1 moi staff     2481306 Oct 29  2011 IMG_0042.JPG
```

I then decided that I only wanted to see the jpg results, so I ran both of these commands, both of which returned no results

```
 ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids | grep "*.JPG"
 ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids | grep "*.JPG$"
```

I would have expected both of the grep commands to filter out all the files ending in PNG, and return all the files ending in JPG, but I got nothing. How am I using grep incorrectly?

I'm working on a Mac OSX 10.9.3

Comment: try `ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids | grep ".JPG"`

Comment: Why use grep at all anyway? Why not just `ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids/*.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some form of answers are **WRONG** although it works like it claims most of the time.

```
grep ".jpg"    #match string "jpg" anywhere in the filename with any character in front of it.
               # jpg -- not match
               # .jpg -- match
               # mjpgsfdfd -- match
grep ".*.jpg"  #basically the same thing as above
grep ".jpg$"   #match anything that have at least 4 chars and end with "jpg"
               # i_am_not_a_.dummy_jpg -- match
grep ".*.jpg$" #the same as above (basically)
```

So to have the best result, try these ones:

```
grep "[.]jpg$" #anything that end with ".jpg"
grep "\\.jpg$" #the same as above, use escape sequence instead
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you are trying to use shell wildcards (`*`) within grep, where the wildcard for a single character is the dot (`.`). Patterns of `.JPG` would match `xxx.NOTAJPG` or `NOTAJPG.txt` if there were such a thing.

The better solution is to just say:

```
ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids/*.jpg
```

If you want case-insensitivity

```
ls Documents/phone_photo_vids/*.{jpg,JPG}
```

which is the same as saying ls `*.jpg *.JPG`

It is not recommended, but if you **really** want to get it working with `grep`, just specify files ending with `jpg` and maybe make it case insensitive with `-i`. You don't need all the `'.*.'` stuff.

```
ls -l Documents/phone_photo_vids | grep -i jpg$
```

Answer (score 1):

Grep uses what is called regex, not what DOS or Windows uses for searches.

The regex expression "*.JPG$" makes no sense to grep, so it probably ignores it. What you want is ".*JPG$"

For [reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
grep "jpg"    #match string "jpg" anywhere in the filename, so file "img.jpg.txt" match too
grep ".*jpg"  #match the whole line with string "jpg", here ".*" stands for any char zero or more times
grep "jpg$"   #match string "jpg" only at the end of line ("img.jpg.txt" will not match)
grep ".*jpg$" #match the whole line only if "jpg" is at the end of line
grep "\.jpg"  #match string ".jpg" - to search literaly for dot one need to escape it with backslash
```

You can create temporary files with `touch "img.jpg.txt" ".jpg"` and use `grep --color=always` to see how above patterns change the output.

BTW, parsing `ls` is usually not good idea, better use `find`:

```
find /path/to/files/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.jpg'
```

Comment: I thing this is actually wrong: grep ".jpg" matches anything contains "jpg" and have at least 1 char in front of it. So for the others. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing this, I've edited my answer.

Comment: There really is no point in any of the `.*` stuff for the purposes of this question. Zero or more characters is the same as matching `jpg` by itself.